# How to prompt for both user and password in curl command?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, curl, marklogic

I am doing a post call to MarkLogic server using CURL command in Ubuntu.

In the command if I'll write like

```
--user username
```

It will prompt for password.

Is there any way to prompt for both username and password?

Basically I don't want to hard code the username and password because in my case username and password will change very frequently So I want user to enter the username and password.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate, but a much cleaner answer.. :)

Comment: Voting to reopen, proposed dupplicate is only about prompting for password, not for the username.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd have to do this in two steps: first read in the username, then use it in your `curl` command. So in `bash` it would come out something like this:

```
read -p "Username: " CURLUSER
curl --user "${CURLUSER}" ...
```

If you wanted to, you could wrap this up in a little script, along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Username: " CURLUSER
curl --user "${CURLUSER}" "$@"
```

Now save that as `curl-with-user.sh`, make it executable, and you can use it as a replacement for `curl`, but one that will start by asking you for the username.

The point of the `"$@"` is to ensure that any arguments you pass to your script also get passed to `curl`.